# Creating a currency translator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I would still consider myself at least a 'semi-noob' at JavaScript.  I'm trying to get prototypal inheritance down & I want to play with closures.  As such, I decided to create a proof-of-concept demo for a currency translator.

I obviously don't have the inheritance 'quite right' and need some feedback there.  I'm sure I'll need to change the formula...so I'm not asking about that part. I also promise to post the finished version when done.

**My Questions Are:**

1. Why doesn't each instance evaluate as Currency?
2. Also, any tips you might have on the general design would be great too.

**The Code**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function Currency(country, code, imageURL, name)
    {
        this.country = country;             //EXAMPLE: America
        this.code = code;                   //EXAMPLE: USD
        this.imageURL = imageURL;           //EXAMPLE: "http://someplace/mySymbol.gif"
        this.name = name;                   //EXAMPLE: Dollar
        this.amount = parseFloat("0.00");   //EXAMPLE: 100
    };
    Currency.prototype.convertFrom = function (currency, factor) {
        this.amount = currency.amount * factor;
    }

    function Dollar(country, code, imageURL, name) {
        Currency.call(this, country, code, imageURL, name);
    };
    Dollar.prototype = new Currency();
    Dollar.prototype.constructor = Dollar();

    function Reais(country, code, imageURL, name) {
        Currency.call(this, country, code, imageURL, name);
    };
    Reais.prototype = new Currency();
    Reais.prototype.constructor = Reais();

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var dollar = new Dollar('America', 'USD', '', 'Dollar');
        var reais = new Reais('Brazil', 'BRL', '', 'Reais');

        dollar.amount = 100;
        reais.amount = 100;

        // Why isnt this evaluating to true?
        if (dollar instanceof Currency)
            alert("dollar is Currency");

        // Why isnt this evaluating to true?
        if (reais instanceof Currency)
            alert("reais is Currency");

        if (dollar instanceof Dollar)
            alert("this Currency is a Dollar");

        if (reais instanceof Reais)
            alert("this Currency is a Reais");

        dollar.convertFrom(reais, 1.2);
        alert("'" + reais.amount + "' Reais converts into '" + dollar.amount + "' Dollars");
    });
-->
</script>
```

**UPDATE: Final Version:**
As promised.  Thanks for the help!

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CurrencyTranslator.ascx.cs" Inherits="Concept.CurrencyTranslator.UserControls.CurrencyTranslator" %>

<style type="text/css">
.currency { }
span.currency { }
input.currency  
{
    text-align: right;
    width: 70px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    // ------------------------
    // Currency - Base Class
    function Currency(country, code, imageURL, name) {
        this.country = country;
        this.code = code;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = parseFloat("0.00");
    };

    // ------------------------
    // Pound
    function Pound(imageURL) {
        Currency.call(this, "Greate Britain", "GBP", imageURL, "Pound");
    };
    Pound.prototype = new Currency();
    Pound.prototype.constructor = Pound;

    // ------------------------
    // Dollar
    function Dollar(imageURL) {
        Currency.call(this, "America", "USD", imageURL, "Dollar");
    };
    Dollar.prototype = new Currency();
    Dollar.prototype.constructor = Dollar;

    // ------------------------
    // Reais
    function Reais(imageURL) {
        Currency.call(this, "Brazil", "BRL", imageURL, "Reais");
    };
    Reais.prototype = new Currency();
    Reais.prototype.constructor = Reais;

    // ------------------------
    // CurrencyElement
    function CurrencyElement(element) {
        this.element = element;
    };
    CurrencyElement.prototype.update = function (rate) {

        var element = jQuery(this.element);
        var float = element.extractValue();
        var value = float * rate;

        if (element.is('input:text'))
            $(this.element).val(jQuery.formatNumber(value.toString(), { format: "#,###", locale: "us" }));

        if (element.is('span'))
            $(this.element).text(jQuery.formatNumber(value.toString(), { format: "#,###", locale: "us" }));
    };

    // ------------------------
    // CurrencyTranslator
    function CurrencyTranslator(currency) {
        this.current = currency;
        this.elements = new Array();
        this.crossRates = new Array();
    };
    CurrencyTranslator.prototype.notify = function (crossRate) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            this.elements[i].update(crossRate.rate);
        };
    };
    CurrencyTranslator.prototype.changeTo = function (currency) {
        var crossRate = this.findCrossRate(this.current, currency);
        this.current = currency;
        this.notify(crossRate);
    };
    CurrencyTranslator.prototype.findCrossRate = function (from, to) {
        var crossRate = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.crossRates.length; i++) {
            if ((this.crossRates[i].from.constructor === from.constructor) && (this.crossRates[i].to.constructor === to.constructor))
                crossRate = this.crossRates[i];
        };
        return crossRate;
    };

    // ------------------------
    // CurrencyCrossRate
    function CurrencyCrossRate(from, to, rate) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.rate = parseFloat(rate);
    };

    // ------------------------
    // Controller - Module
    var currencyTranslator = (function ($) {
        var publicInstances = {};

        publicInstances.controller = controller;
        function controller(currency, crossRates) {

            var self = this;

            this.cssClass = '.currency';
            this.dropDownCssClass = '.currency-dropDown';

            this.ddlCurrency = $(self.dropDownCssClass);
            this.hidCurrentCurrency = $("input[id$='hidCurrentCurrency']");
            this.hidOriginalCurrency = $('input[id$="hidOriginalCurrency"]');

            this.translator = new CurrencyTranslator(currency);

            this.initialize = function () {

                $(self.cssClass).each(function () {
                    self.translator.elements.push(new CurrencyElement(this));
                });

                self.ddlCurrency.change(self.currencyChanged);
            };
            this.currencyChanged = function () {

                var selected = $('option:selected', self.ddlCurrency);
                var currency = new window[selected[0].text](null);

                self.hidCurrentCurrency.val(selected[0].text);
                self.translator.changeTo(currency);
            };
            this.populateCrossRates = function (json) {

                $.each(json, function () {

                    var from = new window[this.From.Name](null);
                    var to = new window[this.To.Name](null);

                    self.translator.crossRates.push(new CurrencyCrossRate(from, to, this.Rate));
                });
            };

            self.initialize();
            self.populateCrossRates(crossRates);
        };

        return publicInstances;
    })(jQuery);
-->
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hidCurrentCurrency" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidOriginalCurrency" runat="server" />
<label style="display:block; font-weight: bold;">Choose a Currency</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" runat="server" CssClass="currency-dropDown" Width="100"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better design since you do assign the instance variables centrally:

```
function Currency(country, code, imageURL, name, amount)
{
    this.country = country;
    this.code = code;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

Next define the method that is to be inherited by the subclasses in Currency's prototype:

```
Currency.prototype.convertFrom = function (currency, factor) {
    this.amount = currency.amount * factor;
}
```

You can use constructor chaining to save some redundant code:

```
function Dollar(country, code, imageURL, name) {
    Currency.call(this, country, code, imageURL, name);
}
```

The first sets the inheritance hierarchy, the latter ensures that the right constructor is used when creating a Dollar with `new`

```
Dollar.prototype = new Currency();
Dollar.prototype.constructor = Dollar;
```

The `instanceof` test will now also succeed. The problem in your code was that your Currency constructor returned an anonymous object. So when assigning `new Currency()`to Dollar.prototype what you actually assigned was that anonymous object instead of Currency.

Comment: @Prisoner ZERO: Oops, I forgot the `this` in Currency.call, sorry. With that, your properties will be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code doesn't run if you don't define dollar before assigning it a prototype so you may prefer the following order.
Next, the .prototype.constructor should simply be Dollar, and not new Dollar().

```
      function Dollar(country, code, imageURL, name) {
            this.country = country;
            this.code = code;
            this.imageURL = imageURL;
            this.name = name;
        };

        Dollar.prototype = new Currency();
        Dollar.prototype.constructor = new Dollar();
```

ok, as for your alert I do have "dollar is instanceof Currency".
However reais is not instance of Dollar. Reais is instance of currency (by its prototype), but Currency doesn't know Dollar, since it's prototype leads directly by default to Object.

Comment: Updated...any other design tips?  Thanks!

Comment: If you stay with prototypal inheritance : instead of assigning country code etc in both dollar and reais, you should call in both Currency.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments)); then in currency assign those variable like you did for dollar